# Как сделать поддержку стримов на Python для PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, потоки-данных

Делаю свой браузер на `PyQt5`. Задаюсь вопросом: как сделать так, чтобы можно было смотреть видеопотоки\стримы на сайтах? Имеется код с `QMediaPlayer`, но вылезает ошибка `DirectShowPlayerService::doRender: Unresolved error code 0x80040218 (IDispatch error #24)`. Кодеки установлены.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QMediaContent
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QLineEdit

class StreamPlayer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Проигрыватель стримов")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)

        self.central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)

        self.video_widget = QVideoWidget(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.video_widget)

        self.media_player = QMediaPlayer(self)
        self.media_player.setVideoOutput(self.video_widget)

        self.url_input = QLineEdit(self)
        self.url_input.setPlaceholderText("Введите URL стрима")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.url_input)

        self.play_button = QPushButton("Просмотр", self)
        self.play_button.clicked.connect(self.play_stream)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.play_button)

    def play_stream(self):
        media_url = self.url_input.text()
        if media_url:
            self.media_player.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl(media_url)))
            self.media_player.play()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    player = StreamPlayer()
    player.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: а это попробовали https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1303906

Comment: Можно спросить что именно?

Comment: А, да. У меня установлен K-Lite Codec Pack Basic

Comment: также вы можете попробовать другой подход, используя `cv2.VideoCapture ...` Примеры такого варианта есть на данном ресурсе и я уверен этот подход будет работать для вас.

Comment: Не понимаю как сделать так, чтобы прямые трансляции начали работать с помощью этого

Comment: Проработайте канал https://www.youtube.com/@pyshine_official/videos там вы найдете много интересного для себя и думаю решите свои текущие проблемы.